# obtaining Array[Boolean] in place of Array[int] in scala

Tags: scala

When I am executing this code, I must get `Array[Int]` consisting of 1 and 0. But the output I am obtaining is `Array[Boolean]` consisting of true and false.
This is creating trouble for further execution. I want to get 0 and 1 only what should i do?

```
val reviewSenti = extracted_reviews.map(reviewText => {
  val reviewWordsSentiment = reviewText.getString(0).split(" ").map(word => {

    var senti: Int = 0;

    if (AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase()).length > 0) {

      senti = AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase())(0)

    };

    senti;

  });

  val reviewSentiment = reviewWordsSentiment.sum

  (reviewSentiment)

  if (reviewSentiment >= 3){
    reviewSentiment == 1;
  }
  else {
    reviewSentiment == 0;
  }
})

reviewSenti: Array[Boolean] = Array(false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, ...
```

Comment: Wow. That's really terrible Scala. In answer to your question: use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: sir when i am using = in place of == then i am getting                                       warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       (reviewSentiment)
        ^
<console>:54: error: reassignment to val
       reviewSentiment = 0;
                       ^
<console>:57: error: reassignment to val
        reviewSentiment = 1;

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Don't use `=` or `==` at all. Just use `1` and `0` as in: `if (reviewSentiment >= 3) 1 else 0`

Comment: sir then will it store the value to reviewSentiment ? and make the array consisting of 0,1 ?

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and can't be run by anyone but you. So you are the only one that can answer the question: "What will happen?" Make the change, run the code, learn the answer.

Comment: `if (x >= 3) x == 1 else x == 0` is true if and only if `x == 0`. I don't know what you tried to do here, but to avoid the annoying situation described by jwvh, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about some of the context of your code. So I might be wrong in some of the assumptions. In the first part of your code you might want to avoid double calling of `AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase())` so basically you could map with something like:

```
  val afinnLookup = AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase())

  if (afinnLookup.length > 0)
    afinnLookup(0)
  else
    0
```

then again I'm not sure about what you get back from `AFFIN` but you could use pattern matching to avoid looking into length and writing it with if:

```
affinLookup match {
  case head :: tail ⇒ head
  case _ ⇒ 0
}
```

or you could even do this with `headOption`: Then you would return an `Option[Int]` but then again it might follow the intention of the library i.e. there is no affinity or something like that. Basically it could be as short as:

```
val reviewWordsSentiment = reviewText.getString(0).split(" ").map(
    word => AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase()).headOption)
```

This would return you Option[Int] this may or may not complicate things for you. If you decide to go down that path here is a very nice guide:
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Or you can avoid Option[Int] by using `fold(0){identity}` or `getOrElse(0)` after headOption by something like:

```
val reviewWordsSentiment = reviewText.getString(0).split(" ").map(
    word => AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase()).headOption.getOrElse(0))
```

This will enable you to do `sum` later and you can even skip assigning it a value you might just need something like at the end.

```
if (reviewWordsSentiment.sum >= 3) 1 else 0
```

Again this is with relatively a lot of assumptions about the code and problem that you provided. I hope this helps or provides some guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

try to make `reviewSentiment == 1;` and another one to just `1` and `0`. This will probably help you.

just like

`if (reviewSentiment >= 3) 1 else 0`